# python command line arguments and invalid syntax

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a run from a code in github.

it has a command line argument like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-m', '--mode', help="Choose a net running mode: training, batch_testing or single_testing", required=True)
    Args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

I want  to run the code by applying:

```
python Boost.py -m training
```

but I get this error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-2-7e83ffb380ee>", line 1
    python Boost.py -m training
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run command line syntax from an interactive `ipython` session.

Comment: yes, also tried it in cmd. same result

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `echo "Hello World"` in `cmd` give you?

Comment: "hello world" !!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying the command line interface from .ipython session, so it is better to avoid.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-m', '--mode', help="Choose a net running mode: training, batch_testing or single_testing", required=True)
Args = parser.parse_args()
print(Args.mode)
```

so it is better to use the above attached working python code then run **python .\Boost.py -m hello**

happy coding ..!

Comment: the error still exits